# Atlases and Transition Maps

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

What is the difference between open sets and open balls?  Definitions of atlases for manifolds do not seem to specify any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open sets are union of open balls. If you have a chart with domain = a open set, you have a chart with domain = a smaller ball.

Comment: Can I ask a follow up question:  Why is it that transition maps map into any given open subset of Rn (say)?  Why are we not restricted more?

Comment: Beacuse a manifold is a "thing" locally as an euclidean space.

Comment: Oh right, of course manifolds are local by definition.